# Update entity list asynchronously and detect when the last item is processed

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, asynchronous

I have an Order class that have a list of order lines :

```
public class Order {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID uuid;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private OrderStatus status;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
}
```

And

```
public class OrderLine {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID uuid;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
  private Order order;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private OrderLineStatus status;
}
```

When i validate my order i send an event for each of his lines, so every lines are validated individually. An other app handle these events and send back validation events for each lines. When my app catch these validations events it update the line status then check if it is the last one to be processed. If it is the last one to be processed it update the order status.

So far i've done this :

```
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    OrderLine orderLine = orderLineService.findById(event.getOrderLineUuid());
    if (!OrderLineStatus.VALIDATED.equals(orderLine.getStatus())
        && !OrderStatus.VALIDATED.equals(orderLine.getOrder().getStatus())) {
      // Update using @Modifying
      orderLineService.updateStatusAndError(
          OrderLineStatus.VALIDATED, null, orderLine.getUuid());
      checkIfLastOrderLine(orderLine.getOrder());
  }

  public void checkIfLastOrderLine(final Order order) {
    // A pessimistic read lock is set on countByStatusAndOrderUuid 
    long stillProcessingCounter = orderLineService
        .countByStatusAndOrderUuid(OrderLineStatus.PENDING_FOR_VALIDATION, order.getUuid());
    if (stillProcessingCounter == 0) { // All lines processed
      // Update order status
      // Do other stuff that need to be done only once
    }
  }
```

But when i'm testing it my order status is updated multiple times. I've also tried to put a synchronized on checkIfLastOrderLine but we have a multiserver service so any server can handle any event.

I was thinking to implement a counter on my order to keep track of validated order lines but i don't know if that's a good idea.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I would try to synchronize on `OrderStatus` field.

In the order repository add the method that will update the order status if the current status is `PENDING_FOR_VALIDATION` (or whatever enum value you use). This method returns a number of modified rows.

```
@Query("update order set order_status = ? where orderId = ? and order_status = 'PENDING_FOR_VALIDATION'", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
int updateOrderStatus(OrderStatus orderStatus, UUID orderId);
```

That means, `updateOrderStatus` should return `1` only for a single event handler.
I believe it should work with `stillProcessingCounter` as follows

```
if (stillProcessingCounter == 0 && updateOrderStatus(VALID, order.getUUID() == 1) {
// do some logic that should be executed only once
}
```

Comment: I ended up locking the whole order with a pessimistic write. Each line have to wait for the order lock before updating and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help